# Trying out Multidimensional Arrays, recieveing Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

I am following Bucky's tutorial series on youtube, but i am having some issues getting this particular one working...
(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbot9MQVHOM for reference)

```
package learning;

public class MDArrays {
    public static void main (String[] args){

        int firstArray[][]={{2,3,4,5,6,7},{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}};
        int secondArray[][]={{4,6,2,3},{2,5,1,6,7},{4,3}};

        System.out.println("Array #1");

        display(firstArray);

        System.out.println("Array #2");
        display(secondArray);

    }

    public static void display(int x[][]){

        for (int row=0; row<x.length; row++){
            for (int column=0; row<x[row].length; column++){

                System.out.print(x[row][column] + "\t");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

The error i am getting goes as follows

```
Array #1
2       3       4       5       6       7       Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at learning.MDArrays.display(MDArrays.java:23)
    at learning.MDArrays.main(MDArrays.java:11)
```

If anyone could help me with this i would be extremely grateful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly mistake, change the condition in inner loop. `row<x[row].length` to `column<x[row].length`.

```
...
for (int column=0; column<x[row].length; column++){
    System.out.print(x[row][column] + "\t");
}
```

Comment: oh... damn... well, thanks for the help, i'll try to be more careful next time i do any coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code to

```
 public static void display(int x[][]){

for (int row=0; row<x.length; row++){
    for (int column=0; column<x[row].length; column++){  // you made a mistake here            

        System.out.print(x[row][column] + "\t");

    }
    System.out.println();
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change-

```
for (int column = 0; row < x[row].length; column++)
```

To-

```
for (int column = 0; column < x[row].length; column++)
```

[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) is thrown because-

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal
>   index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the
>   size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, the int column in your second for loop is ever increasing because there is no condition to stop it. You get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6 because there is no 7th element in x[0].(Index starts from 0, Element starts from 1)  
Solution is to change your second for loop to this

```
for (int column=0; column<x[row].length; column++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a pretty simple mistake.

You just forgot to change the condition in inner for loop.

Instead of

```
for (int column=0; row<x[row].length; column++)
```

use

```
for (int column=0; column<x[row].length; column++)
```